# Dans quel cas utiliser « urgence de » ou « urgence à »?

Tags: expressions, grammaire, choix-de-mot, prépositions

Peut-on utiliser de manière indifférenciée « il y a urgence **à** (accomplir une action) » et  « il y a urgence **de** », ou une règle à ce sujet existe-t-elle ?

Exemples :

- Il y a urgence à agir.
- Il y a urgence de fuir.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à penser qu'on utilise "urgence **à** + _verbe seul_" et "urgence **de** + _groupe verbal avec compléments_"…

Comment: `Il y a urgence` est une expression qui implique la nécessité d'agir rapidement. Pour moi ce serait plutôt: `Il ya urgence, nous devons fuir` et `Il y a urgence, il faut agir`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je dirais plutôt:

> Il est urgent d'agir.

Faire suivre "urgence" d'un verbe ne me paraît pas naturel (et je suppose qu'une règle va me contredire). Par contre, on dit *urgence **de** + substantif*, comme dans:

> L'urgence d'une réforme apparut aux yeux de tous.

(Source: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/urgence)

Answer (score 5):

En fait, ce sont deux constructions différentes. Elles sont correctes, même si le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/urgence) ne donne d'exemple d'aucune des deux. Ni « urgence de », ni « urgence à » ne sont des idiomes en tant que tels, ce sont des constructions valables. Le sens et le niveau de langue sont les mêmes.

« Il y a urgence à agir » suit la même construction que « il y a un intérêt à agir ». Ce n'est pas une construction très productive, mais on peut quand même la retrouver dans d'autres contexte qu'en complément d'« il y a ». Par exemple, une recherche Google me montre « Le FMI souligne l'urgence à agir sur le dossier grec », titre de dépêche Reuteurs qui me paraît idiomatique.

« Il y a urgence d'agir » suit la construction « urgence de + infinitif ». Cette construction me paraît légèrement maladroite : quand je vois « urgence de + infinitif », j'ai envie de corriger en « caractère urgent de + infinitif » (mais ça ne passerait pas du tout dans la phrase originale). Mais elle n'a rien d'incorrect.

Pour la phrase proposée, je préfère [comme Joubarc](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/291/dans-quel-cas-utiliser-urgence-de-ou-urgence-a/293#293) dire « il est urgent d'agir ». Les formulations plus longues ne sont pas fausses ; cette phrase précise se rencontre souvent dans des contextes politiques, où l'on veut convaincre l'interlocuteur, et la formulation plus longue (mais pas trop) donne un peu plus de force à la phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais : Il est urgent de / Il y a urgence à

- Il est urgent de proposer des solutions
- Il y a urgence à agir